# Transfer user data of a Tigase server

Tags: centos, mysql, migration, xmpp

I'm trying to transfer a Tigase XMPP server from an Ubuntu VPS to a CentOS VPS. Unfortunately there isn't any official documentation available and I need to experiment in order to preserve all of the current data.

What I've tried so far:

I. Copy the sql database

1. Install the same version of Tigase to the new server.
2. Dump Tigase's mysql database table from the old server and import it to the new one with --ignore option

Result - server runs and I can create new users, but old users can't log in. I confirmed that user passwords have been correctly copied to the new database and that both databases use the same hashing key.

II. Move the whole Tigase directory and the database

1. Tar zipped the Tigase directory from the old server and the database
2. Extracted them to the new server and overwrote the database to the new server.

Result - Tigase doesn't start and returns various runtime and connection errors.

Question

#### Is there a way to transfer (export/import) the Tigase user data from one server to another?

Update

I found some article concerning importing data, however it's very old-dated: http://www.tigase.org/content/importing-user-data
I think the database structure is different, for example I can't find information about user's rosters, nicks, existing MUCs etc, which I would like to preserve.